# How do I write a conditional statement using jquery that validates a page url or an email?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url, conditional-statements

I have two regular expressions for one user input field that should accept a websites contact page url or an email address. How can I write this in Jquery or Javascript? Here are my two regular expressions.

```
regex for URL "((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])",


regex for email "^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$",

 error messageelse "You must enter a valid email or you must enter a valid url, which starts with http://. The www prefix is optional.")
```

Comment: That regular expression is going to reject a lot of perfectly fine email addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/A77fD/

Example -

```
var url_regex = /((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])/;
var email_regex = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/

$('#test').click(function(){
    console.log(url_regex.test($('#test_field').val()));
    console.log(email_regex.test($('#test_field').val()));

    if(!(url_regex.test($('#test_field').val()) || email_regex.test($('#test_field').val()))){
        alert("You must enter a valid email or you must enter a valid url, which starts with http://. The www prefix is optional.")
    }
})
```

Comment: Pretty please, don't infest the world with yet another ad-hoc email "validator" which accepts invalid addresses and rejects valid ones.

Comment: Haven't checked the regexs. Just answered what the user wanted. But surely he can improve upon the regexs.

Answer (score 0):

use regex.test("url or email")

```
var regexU = /((www\.|(http|https|ftp|news|file)+\:\/\/)[&#95;.a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z0-9\/&#95;:@=.+?,##%&~-]*[^.|\'|\# |!|\(|?|,| |>|<|;|\)])/;
var regexEmail = /^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/

function validate() {
    if( regexUrl.test("url") || regexEmail.test("email")) {
    console.log("valid"); 
    } else {
      console.log("You must enter a valid email or you must enter a valid url, which starts with http://. The www prefix is optional.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using some kind of library to do your validations. No need to reinvent the wheel every time.

jQuery has a plugin that could be suitable: http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation